# Star rates with bootstrap 5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to integrate  this code with the bootstrap icon 5 but the icon does not appear. It s a star rate.
It seems there something wrong somewhere because the icon does not appear
Thank you

the elements

```css
fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 10px;
}

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating>.half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating>input:checked~label,

/* show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,

/* hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,

/* hover current star when changing rating */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,

/* lighten current selection */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h6>Pure CSS Star Rating Widget</h6>
<fieldset class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class="bi bi-star-fill" for="star5" title="5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="bi bi-star-half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class="bi bi-star-fill" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="bi bi-star-half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class="bi bi-star-fill" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="bi bi-star-half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class="bi bi-star-fill" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="bi bi-star-half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class="bi bi-star-fill" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="bi bi-star-half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: looking for your unicode here is what i get : https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=f089  should you use another star character ? https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=stars

Comment: Maybe this is of any help: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements

Comment: did you only forgot to load the font ? ;)

Comment: You aren't loading Bootstrap Icons into the above code. Your CSS references Font Awesome but that also isn't shown as being loaded.